# Cannot match any routes angular 13

Tags: angular

I started learning angular and ran into a routing problem
there are following routing modules in app-routing.module.ts:

```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent } from './p/home/home.component';

import { WorksComponent } from './p/works/works.component';
import { CenzorComponent } from './p/works/cenzor/cenzor.component';
import { UserlistComponent } from './p/works/userlist/userlist.component';
import { TasklistComponent } from './p/works/tasklist/tasklist.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'',redirectTo:'home',pathMatch:'full'},
{ path:'home',component: HomeComponent},
{ path:'',component: WorksComponent,children:[
  {path:'',redirectTo:'works',pathMatch:'full'},
  { path:'cenzor',component: CenzorComponent},
  { path:'userlist',component: UserlistComponent},
  { path:'tasklist',component: TasklistComponent},
] },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './p/home/home.component';
import { WorksComponent } from './p/works/works.component';
import { CenzorComponent } from './p/works/cenzor/cenzor.component';
import { UserlistComponent } from './p/works/userlist/userlist.component';
import { TasklistComponent } from './p/works/tasklist/tasklist.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    WorksComponent,
    CenzorComponent,
    UserlistComponent,
    TasklistComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

home.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="../../assets/images/1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-danger text-center">list of prohibited words</h5>
       
          <a class="btn btn-success" routerLink="censor">censor</a>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="../../assets/images/2.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title text-danger text-center">angular task list</h5>
       
          <a class="btn btn-success" routerLink="tasklist">tasklist</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="../../assets/images/3.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body bg-light">
          <h5 class="card-title text-danger text-center">Angular users list</h5>
       
          <a  class="btn btn-success " routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="userlist">userlist</a>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

I think there is problem with routes, because i get following error in console: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home/userlist'. Anyway i dont know how to handle this
Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your routes set-up. I'll try to clarify.

```
{path:'',redirectTo:'home',pathMatch:'full'},
```

In this, you are saying that when someone goes to `url.com/` they get redirected to `url.com/home` which is all good so far.

In here:

```
{ path:'home',component: HomeComponent},
```

you load homeComponent. All good as well. But then:

```
{ path:'',component: WorksComponent,children:[
  {path:'',redirectTo:'works',pathMatch:'full'},
  { path:'cenzor',component: CenzorComponent},
  { path:'userlist',component: UserlistComponent},
  { path:'tasklist',component: TasklistComponent},
] }
```

In here you are telling the router that `''` path will load the `WorksComponent`, but this will never happen because of the first mentioned thing (you reroute this path to `home`, so user can never get here).

Next, you are adding children to this path. So even if you could access this component, you would need to add a `<router-outlet>` into the markdown of `WorksComponent`.

You are trying to access `home/userlist` which makes me realize that you want to:

1. Add the children properties to `HomeComponent`, that way, this component is the one with access to all paths after it (`url.com/home/*`), so if you add userlist as a child of `HomeComponent` you could route `url.com/home/userlist`, right now this path doesn't exist.
2. Add a `<router-outlet>` to your `HomeComponent`'s html. Inside this router outlet is where the `userlist` component will render. So if you do

```html
    <h1>This is home</h1>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <p>Some text goes here</p>
```

Then the `userlist` component will render between the title, and the text. If that makes sense. Also reroute your `WorksComponent`, it is incongruent for a route to have a `redirectTo` and a component load at the same time.

Comment: Thank You!
I've got one more question: for example by clicking on some button from  HomeComponent.html, i get following adress above http://localhost:4200/home/tasklist, but it should be http://localhost:4200/works/tasklist
how can it be solved?

Comment: probably you are doing a relative routing `routerLink="./tasklist"` or `routerLink="tasklist"`, try doing an absolute routing `routerLink="/works/tasklist"`.

Do check the difference between relative and absolute paths on google

Answer (score 0):

Fransisco explained well, and if I want to sum it up, first you should be careful about order of routes because Router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes.
Second probably need to use / before any paths in your html file like this:
router link="/userlist".